# How to parallelize workflowsets::workflow_map()?

Tags: parallel-processing, modeling, tidymodels

I have a list of models I would like to fit using `workflowsets::workflow_map()`. Here is an example I stole from the documenation. How can I do the model fitting in parallel, i.e., have one core or something similar for `date_lm`,`plus_holidays_lm`, and `plus_pca_lm` each?

A solution from the tidymodels universe is highly preferred to custom solutions.

Thanks,

```
library(workflowsets)
library(workflows)
library(modeldata)
library(recipes)
library(parsnip)
library(dplyr)
library(rsample)
library(tune)
library(yardstick)
library(dials)

# An example of processed results
chi_features_res

# Recreating them:

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
data(Chicago)
Chicago <- Chicago[1:1195,]

time_val_split <-
   sliding_period(
      Chicago,
      date,
      "month",
      lookback = 38,
      assess_stop = 1
   )

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

base_recipe <-
   recipe(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago) %>%
   # create date features
   step_date(date) %>%
   step_holiday(date) %>%
   # remove date from the list of predictors
   update_role(date, new_role = "id") %>%
   # create dummy variables from factor columns
   step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
   # remove any columns with a single unique value
   step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
   step_normalize(all_predictors())

date_only <-
   recipe(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago) %>%
   # create date features
   step_date(date) %>%
   update_role(date, new_role = "id") %>%
   # create dummy variables from factor columns
   step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
   # remove any columns with a single unique value
   step_zv(all_predictors())

date_and_holidays <-
   recipe(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago) %>%
   # create date features
   step_date(date) %>%
   step_holiday(date) %>%
   # remove date from the list of predictors
   update_role(date, new_role = "id") %>%
   # create dummy variables from factor columns
   step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
   # remove any columns with a single unique value
   step_zv(all_predictors())

date_and_holidays_and_pca <-
   recipe(ridership ~ ., data = Chicago) %>%
   # create date features
   step_date(date) %>%
   step_holiday(date) %>%
   # remove date from the list of predictors
   update_role(date, new_role = "id") %>%
   # create dummy variables from factor columns
   step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
   # remove any columns with a single unique value
   step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
   step_pca(!!stations, num_comp = tune())

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

pca_param <-
   parameters(num_comp()) %>%
   update(num_comp = num_comp(c(0, 20)))

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

chi_features_set <-
   workflow_set(
      preproc = list(date = date_only,
                     plus_holidays = date_and_holidays,
                     plus_pca = date_and_holidays_and_pca),
      models = list(lm = lm_spec),
      cross = TRUE
   )

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

chi_features_res_new <-
   chi_features_set %>%
   option_add(param_info = pca_param, id = "plus_pca_lm") %>%
   workflow_map(resamples = time_val_split, grid = 21, seed = 1, verbose = TRUE)

chi_features_res_new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suggest using the [ordinary methods for parallel processing](https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search.html#parallel-processing). This will parallelize within each row of the workflow set.